# QGIS: Label features using field attributes from a one to many related table

Tags: qgis, labeling, sql, relates

Using QGIS it is possible to easily label features from related tables with a 1 to 1 *JOIN*. If the relationship is one to many and *Project Properties RELATIONS* are defined, then only the last related entry seems to be available for labeling (this is only available if a *JOIN* is also defined). For example, if I have a feature set called Countries with field called Country as the related (key) field and a related table fields Country and Flag_Colors, how could I do a label like this: "Name: United States Colors: Red, White, Blue"
I'm hoping since the *Attribute Table Form* has *Expressions* and the *Feature ID panel* both *count* and *display* the 3 colors (i.e. related records) there is some type of SQL expression that can get the kind of Feature label I am describing. See attached screen shot of the current limits of my labeling attempt.

Ay suggestions or ideas?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `relation_aggregate` function with `concatenate` as the aggregation type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create a relation between the two tables via "Project -> Properties->Relations":
[image]

Next, you can use the following expression to label each country with all responding child features and their respective `color`:

```
 'Name: ' || "CNTRY_NAME"  || ' Colors: '|| relation_aggregate(relation:='Country_Colors',aggregate:='concatenate',expression:="Color", concatenator:=', ')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you all for helping with this one. I'd never heard of this call. but it did just what I was hoping for.